# How does phonepe switch works?

Tags: android

I can see multiple apps inside phonepe switch and when I click on them they open in phonepe itself. Is that a webview or app displayed on top of phonepe? If that is app how can i implement in android?

Comment: you can take the apk, decompile it and see for yourself how it works.

Comment: how do I decompile?

Comment: It's not an actual answer.  @Daniel I don't think we can find something by the decompiling app.

Comment: you can find everything related to frontend of the application upon decompiling, of course it becomes harder in cases when proguard is enabled.

Answer (score 3):

It is nothing but just `WebView`.

When we click on any `app` in `PhonePe` it just loads the URL of that website.
It is the easiest way to convert the web into the App.

The website looks like the mobile app because it is Mobile responsive.

you can create own Web App by using `WebView`.

Comment: https://developer.phonepe.com/v4/docs/introduction-to-switch

"Switch is a Merchant's React-native/PWA/M-Site present inside PhonePe's "Switch" section."

Answer (score 2):

Actually apps have another version of this PhonePe and they are being partners with all these companies.

Check this link : [PhonePe Switch on Official Blog](https://blog.phonepe.com/launching-phonepe-switch-your-shortcut-to-a-world-of-apps-41f9d499fc2a)

> We are also focused on bringing more partners across categories,
>   including travel, mobility, food, hyper-local, shopping and
>   entertainment on the platform. Partners like Ola, redBus, Goibibo,
>   Myntra, Delhi Metro, Grofers are already a part of ‘PhonePe Switch’
>   and we are seeing excellent user traction as a result of such
>   partnerships.

So I thought that we have to be partners with them.

What I have noticed:

- It is obviously created differently because when you tap on any app icon, it's displaying the first offer of the respective app.
- Its also asking for permission like "PhonePe wants to connect with OLA and need blah blah blah permission."

I don't know another way to do it.

I hope you will get something from this. Thank you.